# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float' help FOR "nonlin np.dot"

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, nonlinear-functions

```
import numpy as np

def nonlin(x, deriv=False):
    if(deriv==True):
        return(x*(1-x))

        return 1/(1+np.exp (-x))

x = np.array([[0,0,1],
[0,1,1],
[1,0,1],
[1,1,1]])

y = np.array([[0],
[1],
[1],
[0]])


#seed
np.random.seed(1)

#weights/synapses

syn0 = 2*np.random.random((3,4)) - 1
syn1 = 2*np.random.random((4,1)) - 1

#training

for j in range(60000):

#layers (input, hidden, output)
#not a class, just thinking of neurons this way
#np.dot is mattrix multiplication
L0 = x
L1 = nonlin(np.dot(L0, syn0))
L2 = nonlin(np.dot(L1, syn1))

#backpropagation
l2_error = y  - L2
if (j % 10000) == 0:
    print ("Error:" + str(np.mean(np.abs(L2_error))))

#calculate deltas
L2_delta = L2_error*nonlin(L2, deriv=True)

L1_error = L2_delta.dot(syn1.T)

L1_delta = L1_error * nonlin(L1, deriv=True)

#update our synapses
syn1 += L1.T.dot(L2_delta)
syn0 += L0.T.dot(L1_delta)

print ("output after training")
print (L2)
```

The error says:   "  L2 = nonlin(np.dot(L1, syn1))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'"

This is suppose to be a very basic neural network. The portion where there is an error involves adding Layer1 and syn1 as a matrix. I am not sure if I need to change L2 to a float. This is my first time working with matrixes on python.

Comment: Could you please upload the complete code? The value of either variable L1 or syn1 is None. Dot product between variables of NoneType and float fail.Somewhere in your code, functions for L1/sync1 are not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to see people still using [Siraj Raval](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWN3xxRkmTPmbKwht9FuE5A) tutorials to practice on Neural Networks.

Anyways, your error is raised when the function **nonlin** doesn't return anything and thus L1 becomes **None** which is the case when **deriv=False** due to a typo in your code.

I explain:
the **nonlin** function is supposed to act as a sigmoid function when **deriv==False** else act as its derivative.
for this matter, if **deriv==True** we return **x(1-x)** else **the sigmoid**, however your typo prevents the function from seeing the second possibility.

Thus the correct way to define **nonlin** is:

```
def nonlin(x, deriv=False):
    if(deriv==True):
        return(x*(1-x))

    return 1/(1+np.exp (-x))
```

**Alternatively** ( you can also drop the **==True** part )

```
def nonlin(x, deriv=False):
    if deriv:
        return(x*(1-x))
    else:
        return 1/(1+np.exp (-x))
```

Hope this was clear enough.

**Bonus**

even though this isn't what you asked for, I invite you to check the week 5 of this [repository](https://github.com/Vanlogh/ENSTABrain), it explains neural networks well enough in case you want to have a deeper overview.

Comment: Thanks, I hope to use it to predict likely of disease based on genetics research. We shall see.

Comment: @aguy good luck with that, being a Machine Learning enthusiast myself i'm inclined to tell you that in case you need help in some Machine Learning projects, you can contact me on rayhane.mamah@gmail.com, it can never hurt to get some work done

Answer (score 0):

Here we go, as suspected your function 'nonlin' returns None because of intendation error.
Edit your function as below,

```
def nonlin(x, deriv=False):
    if(deriv==True):
        return(x*(1-x))
    return 1/(1+np.exp (-x))  # CHECK THE INDENT HERE
```

I found one more spell error,

#### Change

```
#backpropagation
l2_error = y  - L2
```

into

```
#backpropagation
L2_error = y  - L2
```

Your code should run.